# When should I use different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a search function in AngularJS. Here is my code for controllers:

```
app.controller('SearchController',['$scope', '$window','SearchService',  '$cookies' ,'$location','$routeParams',
function($scope,$window, SearchService, $cookies, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.homePageSearch = function(search) {
            $scope.result = '';
            $scope.count = '';
            SearchService.setSearchData(search);    
            $window.location.href = '/search/';
        }
        $scope.jobDetail = function(){  
           var slug = $location.absUrl().split('/')[4];
           SearchService.getJobDetail(slug).then(function(data){
                console.log(data)
           });
        }
        var url = $location.absUrl().split('/')[3];
        if(url == 'jobdetail'){
           $scope.jobDetail();
        }
    });   
}]);
```

I am calling `homePageSearch` function on page load. After this I am redirecting the page to /jobDetail/ and calling function jobDetail.But the problem is homePageSearch() function is also called on jobDetail page How can I avoid calling homePageSearch() function on jobDetail Page.

Shall I use a different controller for /jobDetail/ page?

I am new to angularJs please suggest me proper way to achieve this.

Comment: I think the problem is not the use of one or two controllers, but more of what are you trying to achieve with so many redirections?

Comment: I am trying to have a search page then when result shows it has a description as different page  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it seems you have two functionalities:

- a research page
- a result page

As it is two differents things on two differents pages, I would suggest you to use two controllers: one for each.

---

Always try to keep your controllers simple: they need to know how to do a *specific* task.

I highlighted the relevant parts from the [**Angular documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

> In general, a Controller **shouldn't try to do too much**. It should
>   contain **only the business logic needed for a single view**.
>
> The most common way to keep Controllers slim is by encapsulating work
>   that doesn't belong to controllers into services and then using these
>   services in Controllers via dependency injection. This is discussed in
>   the Dependency Injection and Services sections of this guide.

---

Furthermore, I suggest you to read [**Divide and conquer**](https://frontify.com/blog/divide-and-conquer-an-overview-about-modular-front-end-architectures), is it an interesting guid about front-end architectures.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough reputation as I am new to stack overflow, so I am posting an answer right now.

It appears from your comments that you have two different pages. So, you should definitely have two different controllers one for each. You can specify that easily using routers. I prefer using ui-router instead of ng-router.

Create a `router.js` file as below. You can specify your controllers to each page like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/views/search.html', 
        controller: 'SearchController'
    })
    .state('results', {
        url: '/results',
        templateUrl: '/views/result.html', 
        controller: 'ResultController'
    });
```

Then, you already have an idea on how to use controllers. One more important thing, please avoid using `$window.location.href`, because of the reason that it refreshes your page, that means it would re-initiate your application.

In fact, you should use `$state.go()` (if you are using ui-router) or `$location.path()` (if you are using ng-router)

Comment: Cool.Thanks for telling will use $location.path() and two different controllers

Comment: Sure, Happy to help :)